# Get name of deleted image

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I just started to work with fine-uploader because it looks really great.

But of course that i have a problem. I would like to send 1 more parameter when you click on DELETE button. This parameter should be the name of the image that will be deleted. 
What i don't know is how to get that name. i Tried to add onclick event as a parameter in html element but there is a problem with timing because of async.

In code i found only this:[image: {filename}]
where {filename} represents name of the image, but i have no idea, how to add it here: [image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add parameters to the delete file request dynamically (per-file or for all files) use [the `setDeleteFileParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setDeleteFileParams). For example:

```
callbacks: {
   onSubmitDelete: function(fileId) {
      var fileName = this.getName(fileId);
      this.setDeleteFileParams({fileName: fileName}, fileId);
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly.. i searched for something like this.getName but i did not find it. Maybe i am stupid only

Answer (score 0):

try this to get file name

//Using jQuery

```
$("#fineUploader").on("onSubmitDelete", function(event,id,name){
 file_name = $(this).fineUploader("getName", id);

})
```